# Flask - WTForms - two routes, need to call form twice?

Tags: flask, routes, flask-wtforms

- I have a route which displays a page with a form.
- When I submit the form, it calls another route, where I process the form
- This route then redirects to the previous route and displays the initial page

My question is: is it correct that I need to call the form on both routes?

```
@route('/')
def home():
    form = MyForm()
    return render_template('index.html', form = form)

@route('/process_form')
    form = MyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        #  process form data here
    return redirect(url_for('home')
```

How would you guys do it? I could also submit the form to the same page and do the form processing there, but it could become messy because I will eventually have more than one form on the page, with multiple processing routes.

Thanks 
D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is likely that the form submission will be sent in POST instead of GET.
2. If a web page has more than one forms, each form will likely has its own model (i.e. Class) and form instantiations. Therefore there should be no 'messy' about it.
3. The messiness is not about the form or the route, it is about why a web page has so many forms in one place?

Personally I found it is much cleaner to keep both GET and POST requests under one route:

```
@route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    comment_form = CommentForm()
    subscription_form = SubscriptionForm()
    if subscription_form.validate_on_submit():
        # process subscription form
        redirect(url_for('home')
    if comment_form.validate_on_submit():
        # process comment form
        redirect(url_for('home')
    return render_template('index.html', subscription_form=subscription_form, comment_form=comment_form)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind... I was just trying to avoid having a large route doing too many different things.